# Difference between AR(1) lagged models with exogenous variables versus ARIMA(1,0,0) models with exogenous variables

Tags: time-series, arima

Assume a general time series $y_t$ for $t = 1, \cdots, T$ and a sequence of known exogenous variables $x_t$.

Consider the two options:

Fitting the parameters $a$ and $b$ of the lagged model $y_t = a y_{t-1} + b x_t + u_t$ with $\{u_t\}$ standard noise.

On the other hand, fitting the parameters $c$ and $b$ of the model $y_t = b x_t + n_t$ with $n_t = c n_{t-1} + u_t$ [i.e., using ARIMA(1,0,0) with the same exogenous regressors]

I am wondering what is the relation between these two approaches, as they both seem to account for dynamic effects in the time series, such as e.g., trends.

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

Comment: thank you for the reference, this is quite helpful. I was wondering about further insights into the forecasting properties of the models